# Result error in implementation of trigonometric function by Newton Raphson method in PYTHON

Tags: python, trigonometry, numerical-methods, newtons-method, numerical-analysis

trigonometric function by Newton method is giving wrong results

```
def func(x):
    return radians(math.sin(x)+log(x)+1)

def derivFunc(x):
    return radians((1/x) + math.cos(x))
```

> #sin(x)+log(x)+1 --is the function i want to apply method on

```
**# Function to find the root**
def newtonRaphson(x):
    h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)
    while abs(h) >= 0.0001:
        h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)
        # x(i+1) = x(i) - f(x) / f'(x)
        x = x - h
    print("The value of the root is : ",
          "%.4f" % x)

x0 = 0.03  
newtonRaphson(x0)
```

Comment: I see `deriveFunc`, where is `func`?

Comment: @AlanHoover its there now .. some editing mistake

Comment: What is `radians`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `radians`, which  multiplies a part of an expression by `pi/180.0`. Remove all of its mentions, and it should be fine.

**EDIT**

The below works absolutely fine now:

```
import math
def func(x):
    return math.sin(x)+math.log10(x)+1

def derivFunc(x):
    return (1/x) + math.cos(x)
#sin(x)+log(x)+1 --is the function i want to apply method on

# Function to find the root
def newtonRaphson(x):
    h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)
    while abs(h) >= 0.0001:
        h = func(x) / derivFunc(x)
        # x(i+1) = x(i) - f(x) / f'(x)
        x = x - h
    print("The value of the root is : ",
          "%.4f" % x)

 x0 = 0.03  
 newtonRaphson(x0)
```

Comment: and what about the sin and cos... as in calculator we have to set mode to RADIAN in order to obtain correct results ... here it is not working properly with or without radian giving the same answer

Comment: @ashiqpervez This is not a calculator. The code in the answer (basically yours, with typos fixed and radians removed) works fine.

Comment: still same previous results

Comment: @ashiqpervez I get: The value of the root is :  0.2793 which is correct.

Comment: i am getting the same .. but correct value is 0.082

Comment: @ashiqpervez Plug in the value into sin(x) + log(x) +1, and see that you get close to zero.